# angular expand/shrink div - not accordian or collapse

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using angular bootstrap. I want to be sure I'm not reinventing the wheel here, because I'm not finding accordian or collapse are quite what I want.

I am displaying a large string - possibly several lines - but by default, I only want to take up two lines on-screen, and have the rest of the string cut off. To see the rest of the string, the user would roll over the div and click to expand it downwards, showing the whole thing.

default:

```
[ One AND two AND three OR ]
[ four OR five NOT six ... ]
```

after activating:

```
[ One AND two AND three OR ]
[ four OR five NOT six AND ]
[ seven AND eight AND nine ]
[ NOT (ten Or eleven)      ]
```

Unlike accordian, there should be no title, but it should always shows some (two lines) of the content.
Unlike collapse, it should not collapse all the way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you started. `limitTo` filter works on characters, not words (unless you send an array). Put some data in your controller and check it out.

```
<div ng-click="expand=!expand">
  <span ng-hide="data.length<=10 || expand">{{data|limitTo:10}} ...</span>
  <span ng-show="data.length<=10 || expand">{{data}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've found a different way to do the actual clipping. ng-click toggles the wrapper height between 20px and 100%. But I'm finding this is much more complex than that. I need to indicate a 'clickable' state, so the user knows there's more. But it should *only* be clickable if the text *does* extend to another line (otherwise clicking is redundant). So, it's turning out to be quite sophisticated - which brings me back to searchinhg for an existing plugin.